# How do I add a SOAP template from XSD in soapUI when XML extension is in place?

Tags: testing, soap, wsdl, automated-tests, soapui

I need to make a large number of SOAP test cases to automate the testing process of an application.

Currently, the architecture requires that a single "generic" SOAP method is invoked with an object of a generic type. Each "real" operation is defined by an element in the generic object and requires an object of an extended type to be used as input.

When I create the request template with soapUI, I only get the generic object elements, but I would like to add the empty template for a specific XSD type that is defined in my current schema to be used.

If I use `xsi:type` then soapUI correctly says that my markup is not valid against the schema (missing required elements), but I can't manage to get a *ready-to-fill* XML template.

Can you help me?

Example

genericRequest is made of

```
<genericRequest>
    <methodName>specificMethodName</methodName>
    <authenticationID>ABCDEF</authenticationID>
</genericRequest>
```

sumReuqest (extending genericRequest) for a "sum" operation is made of

```
<sumRequest>
    <methodName>specificMethodName</methodName>
    <authenticationID>ABCDEF</authenticationID>
    <addend>5</addend>
    <addend>3</addend>
</sumRequest>
```

I would ultimately like soapUI to fill a SOAP template with empty *addend* item (of course I work with lots of elements, and they are structured too!!)

Comment: Please vote the answer, if you think this helped you :)

Comment: To be honest (really honest!) I accepted your answer because I considered my question as "dangling" after so many months. I'm no more on that project, so while your answer looks correct to me, it's unfortunately helpless. Nobody denies an upvote to a correct answer anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to create two resources in soaupUI one for generic request and other for operation request, I know right now its pain to create each resource for each operation, but soapUI is developed like that or if you think any of the parameters listed : http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/understanding-rest-parameters.html could help, you could define parameters as one of the above.

you could try using QUERY or MATRIX style parameters in your resource.